# ggerrorplot: how can I change the colors on the Plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

Is it possible to give every variable a different color and how?

I would like to keep the legend.

Please note that it is made with ggerrorplot function.

Comment: Could you please share your data and code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different `palette` in your `ggerrorplot` function. I will use the `ToothGrowth` dataset as an example:

> the color palette to be used for coloring or filling by groups.
> Allowed values include "grey" for grey color palettes; brewer palettes
> e.g. "RdBu", "Blues", ...; or custom color palette e.g. c("blue",
> "red"); and scientific journal palettes from ggsci R package, e.g.:
> "npg", "aaas", "lancet", "jco", "ucscgb", "uchicago", "simpsons" and
> "rickandmorty".

For example use `palette="Paired"` for blue color:

```
df<- ToothGrowth

library(ggpubr)
ggerrorplot(df, x = "dose", y = "len",
            color = "supp", palette = "Paired",
            error.plot = "pointrange",
            position = position_dodge(0.5))
```

Output:

[image]

Or `palette="npg"`:

[image]